# Website responsiveness tests - google, screenfly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsiveness

Is google 100% reliable for testing website responsiveness?

I'm also using this site 'http://pt.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php', but there are some resolutions that are different with the google emulator.
Another question, should I reproduce on this site as, with the option 'in the browser', or with this option unchecked?

Please help me. It is the first website I am making for a company and I have questions about how to test the responsiveness of the website

Website link: file:///D:/Programming/Git-repositories/Cantacom-ProjectForDeveloperVacancy/1-htmlCssJs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

for different browsers use different styles, -moz- for firefox, -webkit- for webkit apps, ...

Comment: it will help improve responsiveness